# Should OCaml compilation with custom linking work in Windows (via MinGW)?

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, ocaml

I want to compile an OCaml program interfacing with C code, using a MinGW-based GCC, and using separate compilation (GCC produces the `.o`, then `ocamlopt` produces the final executable).

It's not clear to me if (1) this should work on Windows and, if so, (2) which command-line arguments are necessary.

I'm using Jonathan Protzenko's [OCaml on Windows installer](http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/) to install OCaml 4.02.1 along with a Cygwin shell (note that it uses a native windows OCaml compiler, not a Cygwin-based one). I installed gcc using [Nuwen's MinGW](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (but had the same issue when using Strawberry Perl's gcc).

Here's my source code:

C file (`tc.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "caml/mlvalues.h"

value print(value unused) {
  printf("hello from C\n");
  return Val_unit;
}
```

OCaml file (`t.ml`):

```
external print : unit -> unit = "print"

let () =
  Printf.printf "platform: %s\n" (Sys.os_type);
  print ();
```

The following works just fine:

```
and@win7 $ ocamlopt t.ml tc.c -o t.exe
and@win7 $ ./t.exe
platform: Win32
hello from C
```

However, if I use a `.o` instead of a `.c`, it doesn't work:

```
and@win7 $ gcc tc.c -c -I c:/OCaml/lib -o tc.o
and@win7 $ ocamlopt t.ml tc.o -o t.exe
** Cannot resolve symbols for tc.o:
 puts
** Fatal error: Unsupported relocation kind 0004 for puts in tc.o
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
```

Both versions work fine on Linux.

I wonder if it's just some silly mistake that I can quickly fix by giving the right arguments to gcc/ocamlc/ocamlopt, or if it's a current limitation of OCaml's native compilation on Windows.

**Edit**: camlspotter identified the cause, so in retrospect, I did not need Nuwen's MinGW at all. OCaml on Windows already includes a MinGW-based C compiler, except that it is called `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and not `gcc`.

Comment: Just for the record: Nuwen's is ___not___ a MinGW distribution! To describe it as such is an infringement of the trademark granted to [SPI-Inc](http://www.spi-inc.org/corporate/trademarks/), on behalf of [MinGW.org](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the remark, should I edit the question to clarify it or is your comment sufficient?

Comment: You should edit the question, to make it clear that you have chosen a derived fork of MinGW, (which is legitimate, but not supported by the trademark owner). You should also remove the `mingw` tag; `mingw-w64` may be an acceptable alternative, (but nuwen isn't strictly that fork either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using a wrong C compiler or without appropriate options.  The best way is to use the same C compiler + options used to build OCaml.  You can check it by `ocamlc -config`:

```
$ ocamlc -config
version: 4.02.3
standard_library_default: C:/ocamlmgw64/lib
standard_library: C:/ocamlmgw64/lib
standard_runtime: ocamlrun
ccomp_type: cc
bytecomp_c_compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O -mms-bitfields -Wall -Wno-unused
bytecomp_c_libraries: -lws2_32
native_c_compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O -mms-bitfields -Wall -Wno-unused
native_c_libraries: -lws2_32
native_pack_linker: x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld -r  -o 
ranlib: x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib
...
```

For example, the above shows that my OCaml compiler is built over Cygwin 32 bit environment with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. The same applies for the linker and `ranlib`.  Since you can compile C with OCaml code with `ocamlopt`, the same C compiler must be already installed in your environment.

Building OCaml compiler by yourself to make sure the same C compiler is used both for C and OCaml may be the best way to avoid this sort of C compiler mismatch.

Comment: Indeed, the OCaml on Windows installer already included a GCC but I had not realized, because its binary was `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and there was no `gcc` binary anywhere. OCaml was using that one instead of the MinGW one.